# Gremlin Java - Set list of values for property

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I am using gremlin-java to access AWS Neptune. I want to set the value of a vertex property with a list of values. I tried doing the following:

```
g.V(<id of vertex>).property(Cardinality.set, "countries", new HashSet<>()).next();
```

I am getting the following exception when I execute it:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: {"requestId":"39207d15-75df-4e04-9c25-574070c94687","code":"UnsupportedOperationException","detailedMessage":"Unsupported property value type: java.util.LinkedHashSet"}
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:259)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:198)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:124)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:68)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketClientHandler.java:89)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
```

I found online that to set the value of a property with a list of values, I can invoke the property() function multiple times with the same property key. But I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way to do it other than having to loop through all the values I have in the set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you need to call `property(SET, 'key', ...)` multiple times. If you find that you do that enough in your code, you might considering writing a [Gremlin DSL](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-dsl) to extend the language to allow for you to specify a `Set` that will then convert to the expected syntax.

Comment: DSL looks helpful for me. Thank you.